# Ionic wont show BLOB images

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an array contains BLOB Images

```
images[]
    0: {id: "1146", image: Blob}
    1: {id: "1147", image: Blob}
    2: {id: "1148", image: Blob}
    3: {id: "1149", image: Blob}
    4: {id: "1150", image: Blob}
    length: 5
```

on HTML page i have:

```
<img [src]="showImage(item.id)" />
```

My Typescript code is:

```
showImage(itemID) {
  let item = [];
  item = this.images.filter(x => x.id == itemID);
  let image: Blob;
  image = item[0].image;
  let imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
  return this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageURL);
}
```

***This code is working fine on Web browser***

**but** when i run it on DevApp application or on an emulator i got this error

```
Runtime Error
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Ionic info

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.2
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 10.14.2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

After too many tries it seems that the problem is: **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0+**

remove then add 1.2.1 version solved my problem.

```
ionic cordova plugins rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```